# Wordpress scripts not loading because of SSL

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration

I just migrated my site to AWS EC2. The basic HTML of the site loads, but CSS and JS fail. From inspecting the source, Wordpress is adding "https" to my script links. I had an SSL certificate at my old cloud provider but not AWS.

How do I stop it from using Https?

This is my .htaccess (from the wordpress document root):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /html
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^/wordpress(.*) /$1
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

#Redirect 301 /node/ /old/node/

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
~
```

And my wp-config includes:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'USER');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'PWD');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

#define('RELOCATE',true);

define('WP_HOME','http://35.155.137.83/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://35.155.137.83/');
define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
```

I also updated the home_url in the wp_options database table.

Comment: Just confirming, you did change the WordPress Address (URL) & the Site Address (URL) to http from general settings aye?

Comment: The admin gui completely fails to load for me, so no

Comment: Do you have access to phpmyadmin?

Comment: I don't think we use that? Sorry I'm brand new to this.

Comment: I think you have access to your cPanel. Find phpmyadmin there & access your database. Find wp_options (could be a different prefix) & there you will find the site url & the site address. Change it to http:// & hit go. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I've already done this directly through mysql, that would be the same right?

Comment: Yep, that should do it. Sorry, that's all I know. Hope someone helps you with this. Just try this in your htaccess if you haven't tried.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Should I replace anything or just add this to htaccess?

Comment: You can try adding this just before # BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]